# Stripe's partner payment options redirect back to return_url if customer exits payment modal

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-payments-js

For instance, on a Stripe web element, if the Affirm or Klarna payment options are used, it shows a payment modal for the customer to complete the process.

If the customer changes their mind and clicks the [X] icon to close the modal, then the Stripe element redirects back to the `return_url` value instead of taking the customer back to the payment form. This will cause the purchase payment to not go thru but will still send all the payment details to the `return_url` as if they did.

Is there a way change this behavior so that exiting a partner payment form just takes the customer back to the original form so they can choose a different payment method?

My setup uses this JS code to create the payment element:

```
elements = stripe.elements({
    clientSecret: token.client_secret
});
const paymentElement = elements.create('payment', {
    layout: {
        type: 'accordion',
        defaultCollapsed: false,
        radios: false,
        spacedAccordionItems: true
    },
    fields: {
        billingDetails: {
            name: 'never',
            email: 'never',
            phone: 'auto',
            address: 'auto',
        }
    }
});
paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');
```

And this code when the payment is confirmed:

```
const {error} = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    elements,
    confirmParams: {
        payment_method_data: {
            billing_details: {
                name: document.querySelector('#name').value.trim(),
                email: document.querySelector('#email').value.trim(),
            }
        },
        return_url: 'https://example.com/receipt',
    },
});
```

But obviously the payment is not actually confirmed...they just changed their mind on which payment method to use.

The payment intent is created on the server side and returned in the `token` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's normal. The `return-url` is not a success url, it's the only link your customer can be redirected to post confirm.

The documentation clearly suggests that you don't know what status the payment is going to be when your customer is redirected:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/affirm/accept-a-payment?platform=web#web-collect-payment-method-details

> The return_url should correspond to a page on your website that provides the status of the payment, by verifying the status of the PaymentIntent when rendering the return page.

You're supposed to either rely on webhooks or API polling to check on that status and perform appropriate actions - i.e. log purchase or prompt customer to try again.

Comment: The redirect is happening in JS. So you are saying I have to just let it hit the receipt page and poll the DB in a loop while waiting for either an async webhook request to update the data or repeatedly poll Stripe's API to make sure the payment_intent has the right status?

Comment: no, you don't have to poll in a loop (maybe 'polling' was a poor choice of words in my answer). When your customer hits the `return_url`, Stripe injects the Payment Intent ID as query param - you can retrieve that (preferably serverside) to check the status. Otherwise use webhooks.